# Write to Mac OS X Console logs from shell script or command line

Tags: macos, bash, shell, logging

Is there a simple, portable (preferably works with older OS X versions) way to write a message to the Mac OS X Console logs from a shell script?

Comment: Something like `echo`?

Comment: Exactly, I'd like to replace `echo` calls in a shell script with logging to the console.

Comment: Sorry, I realized I forgot to include the word "log" in my question. I mean the logs that are viewed from the Console.app program in Mac OS X.

Comment: Ohh, the [Console app](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Console_(OS_X)), not Terminal. I see what you mean now.

Comment: This would be better for Ask Different: http://apple.stackexchange.com/ ; also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20104/how-do-i-execute-command-line-scripts

Comment: I added shell script to title (was already in text) and voted for reopen. Shell scripting falls under stackoverflow under SO's scope.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
syslog -s -l error "message to send"
```

will log the message as something like

```
May 29 17:15:09 hostname syslog[22316]: message to send
```

You can customize things by using `-k`, which expects a list of alternating keys and values, for example

```
syslog -s -k Facility com.apple.console \
             Level Error \
             Sender MyScript \
             Message "script says hello"
```

would produce

```
May 29 17:22:21 hostname MyScript[22343]: script says hello
```

(setting the `Facility` to `com.apple.console` makes it a "console" message, equivalent to stdout output from a double-clicked bundled application, and retrievable using `syslog -C`)

Answer (score 2):

May be you should try the `syslog` command with -s option? See `man syslog` for details.

For example `sudo syslog -s o.O`